# How to deny connections to localhost and force to use FQDN instead

Tags: mysql

I have a server running Apache and MySQL. Connections to MySQL work fine when using `localhost` in the connection settings.

Now I'd like to force our developers to use a FQDN instead of localhost. This is because we're planning to move the MySQL servers from the application servers to a MySQL cluster. Then we can transparantly move things without the developers having to modify connection settings.

So I created a CNAME DNS record `mysql.company.com` pointing to the server that is running MySQL. Later on we can point this to the MySQL cluster.

I opened port 3306 on the server, allowed the MySQL users to connect from any host (%) and added the `bind-address = mysql.company.com` setting to the my.cnf (I also tried with the actual IP of the server, didn't work either). Also omitting the `bind-address` setting didn't work.

From the server `mysql --host=mysql.company.com --user=root --password` works fine.

When testing with a simple PHP script (see below) that's running on the same server, I always get a `Permission denied` error for the FQDN as server name. Using `localhost` as the server name works fine.

```
<?php

$servername = "mysql.company.com";
//$servername = "localhost";
$username = "tester";
$password = "my_awesome_pass";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

What am I doing wrong to achieve what I need? And how can I disable MySQL connections to `localhost` (maybe with the firewall?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, a few minutes after posting a question, I found the answer myself. The issue was SELinux. It was set on enforced; permissive made it work instantly. Now I'll have to figure out a way to make it work with the enforced mode.

The following appeared in the audit.log:

> type=AVC msg=audit(1429781752.260:6738): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=40354 comm="httpd" dest=3306 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:mysqld_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket

Answer (score 0):

Be sure `skip_name_resolve` is `OFF`.

`GRANT` access for the users from their hosts.

Remove non-root grants for `localhost` (when you want to really force them to convert).

I assume you have user(s) that are `GRANTed` access only to the application database(s).